# Definir uma variável em tempo de execução a partir de uma string e um objeto python

Tags: python, variáveis

Quero adicionar uma variável ao meu código ou na memoria em tempo de execução, estou procurando algo parecido com isso desde ontem e não consigui obter o resultado desejado.

Digamos que eu tenha um objeto: (`<bound method Menu.adSabor of <__main__.Menu object at 0x00000219635E6040>>`), e quero referência lo em tempo de execução.
por exemplo: (`def referencia(self, 'nome_da_variavel_em_string', <bound method Menu.adSabor of <__main__.Menu object at 0x00000219635E6040>>`, o `nome_da_variavel_em_string` será a nova referencia do objeto, onde consigo chamar ele com `self.nome_da_variavel_em_string`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi direito, você quer **acessar uma variável usando um string que contém o nome da variável**.

Se a variável for global, você pode utilizar a função `globals`, que retorna um dicionário contendo todas as variáveis globais, e acessar sua variável de interesse usando seu nome como chave:

```
X = "Olá"
retorno = globals()["X"]
print(retorno)  # printa "Olá"
```

De maneira equivalente, você pode usar a função `locals` caso a variável seja uma variável local (ex: definida dentro do corpo de uma função):

```
def f():
    Y = 5
    return locals()["Y"]

print(f())  # printa 5
```

Ainda, caso sua variável esteja definida em algum outro módulo, ou então seja um método/atributo de um objeto, você pode usar a função `getattr`, passando para dentro dela o seu módulo/objeto e o nome do atributo desejado:

```
import meu_modulo

print(getattr(meu_modulo, "Z"))  # printa o valor de meu_modulo.Z
```

```
class A:
    valor = 10

instancia = A()
print(getattr(instancia, "valor"))  # printa 10
```

Dito tudo isso, eu recomendo a você refletir se não faria mais sentido no seu código usar um dicionário ou alguma outra estrutura de dados para manter referências aos seus objetos de interesse. Acessar diretamente o dicionário `globals` parece um pouco obfuscado - se você precisa de referências a seus objetos, crie alguma estrutura que as mantenha. Explícito é melhor que implícito ;-)

Edit:

Se você quiser **criar/modificar** um método ou atributo de um objeto, pode usar a função `setattr`:

```
class A:
    valor = 10

    def metodo(self):
        return self.valor

setattr(A, "novo_metodo", A.metodo)

instancia = A()
print(instancia.novo_metodo())  # printa 10
```

Note que `A.novo_metodo` é apenas uma cópia de `A.metodo` - ambos existem dentro do corpo da classe. Se quiser deletar o método antigo, é necessário usar `del A.metodo`.

Se quiser adicionar ou modificar uma variável global/local pelo nome, terá de modificar o dicionário retornado por`globals`/`locals`, respectivamente. Entretanto eu não recomendo esta abordagem, tanto por obfuscar ainda mais o código, quanto por potencialmente modificar algum valor do qual Python depende. Novamente, faz mais sentido definir um dicionário próprio para isso.

Comment: essa é uma maneira legal, mas tem como eu referenciar? eu consigo chamar uma determinada função com ```self.nome_da_função``` , porém eu quero mudar esse nome para outro usando uma string

Comment: @HeitorTasso editei a resposta e acrescentei mais um exemplo, veja se te ajuda.

Comment: ajudou muito, agradeço pela atenção.